# How is a jQuery class selector faster than a jQuery wrapper of querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is this:

```
var e = $(".elem2");
```

faster than this:

```
var e = document.querySelectorAll(".elem2");
d = $(e);
```

http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-jquery-variable-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid. I forgot all about `document.getElementsByClassName(class)` :(

jQuery's probably does a check whether or not it's supported / what the query is. Sees it's a simple class selector and uses `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelectorAll` because it's way faster.

Answer (score -1):

because 
      document.querySelectorAll(".elem2");
check all the tag where .elem2 is used but other just display first occurence

Comment: Are you sure Mudassar Ali?

Answer (score -1):

I thought that the latest jQuery versions use .querySelector/all by default if the browser is compatible